# Split a div to two clickable areas

Tags: html, css

I am trying to separate the divs so that the left green piece is clickable and the right one is clickable again just to run another function. Specifically, I want to put the red trash icon to the right.
How can I achieve this?

[image]

```css
.channels {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="channels" *ngFor="let channel of conversationList" (click)="onClickChat(channel)">
  <div class="chat_list">
    <div class="chat_people">
      <div class="chat_ib">
        <h5><strong>{{ channel.username }}</strong></h5>
        <div *ngIf="channel.sender_id !== myUserId &&  channel.is_read == 0"><span class="badge badge-danger">New</span></div>
        <p>Last message:{{ channel.message}} </p>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-0" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" (click)="deleteConversation(channel)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is use bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="channels" *ngFor="let channel of conversationList" (click)="onClickChat(channel)">
  <div class="chat_list">
    <div class="chat_people">
      <div class="chat_ib">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
              <h5><strong>{{ channel.username }}</strong></h5>
              <div *ngIf="channel.sender_id !== myUserId &&  channel.is_read == 0"><span class="badge badge-danger">New</span></div>
              <p>Last message:{{ channel.message}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-0" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" (click)="deleteConversation(channel)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap h5, div, and p inside a div and then apply the flexbox. Something like this:

```css
.chat_ib {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="channels" *ngFor="let channel of conversationList" (click)="onClickChat(channel)">
  <div class="chat_list">
    <div class="chat_people">
      <div class="chat_ib">
      <div>
        <h5><strong>{{ channel.username }}</strong></h5>
        <div *ngIf="channel.sender_id !== myUserId &&  channel.is_read == 0"><span class="badge badge-danger">New</span></div>
        <p>Last message:{{ channel.message}} </p>
       </div>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-0" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" (click)="deleteConversation(channel)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To prevent firing function `onClickChat` when you click on delete button. You can do something like this:

```
function deleteConversation(event, channel) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    "your delete logic"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve separation of the two areas by first structuring the html to something like this

```html
<div class="channels" *ngFor="let channel of conversationList" (click)="onClickChat(channel)">
  <div class="chat_list">
    <div class="chat_people">
      <div class="chat_ib">
        <div class="chat_user_container">
          <h5><strong>{{ channel.username }}</strong></h5>
          <div *ngIf="channel.sender_id !== myUserId &&  channel.is_read == 0"><span class="badge badge-danger">New</span></div>
          <p>Last message:{{ channel.message}} </p>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-0" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" (click)="deleteConversation(channel)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After restructuring the html you could use `display:flex` on `.chat_ib` for having them both side by side

Then you could add separate click events to the button on the right side and the new `chat_user_container`

You could then specify a  width for the button then set the width of the `chat_user_container` to 100% and remove any margin from both of them.

This would help you achieve the desired outcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by using display:flex.

Please check the attached code snippets. let me know if you face any issues there .

Thanks :)

```css
.chat_people {
display: flex; 
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.chat_ib, .delete-button{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="channels" *ngFor="let channel of conversationList">
  <div class="chat_list">
    <div class="chat_people" (click)="onClickChat(channel)">
      <div class="chat_ib">
        <h5><strong>{{ channel.username }}</strong></h5>
        <div *ngIf="channel.sender_id !== myUserId &&  channel.is_read == 0"><span class="badge badge-danger">New</span>
        <p>Last message:{{ channel.message}} </p></div></div>
        <div class="delete-button" (click)="onClickTrash(channel)">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-0" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" (click)="deleteConversation(channel)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```